# Viewing a generated data file in a directory from graylog

Tags: graylog

My application generates few data files/output files in a folder
I want to Open and view these files from gralog web. Is there any tools which I can use

Answer (score 0):

Graylog itself doesn't support reading from files directly. In order to view the files contents in the Graylog web interface, you first need to index them.

For ingesting those files into Graylog, you have several possibilities:

- rsyslog with `imfile` input module: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html
- nxlog with file input module: http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/nxlog-docs/en/nxlog-reference-manual.html#im_file
- logstash with file input plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html
- Filebeat: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html

All of those support sending data to Graylog, e. g. directly via GELF.